# Using pythoncyc to get ec-code of a reaction

Tags: python

I am trying to collect the ec-code (and gene) of a reaction. I have tried the following:

```
import pythoncyc
pgdb = pythoncyc.PGDB("sco")
r = "RXN1A0-6128"
gene = "SCP1.233B"
enzyme = pgdb.enzymes_of_reaction(r)
enzyme = pgdb.enzymes_of_gene(gene)
pgdb.full_enzyme_name(enzyme)
```

However, I only get an enzyme id, and not the ec-code, which is visible on [biocyc](https://biocyc.org/SCO/NEW-IMAGE?type=REACTION&object=RXN1A0-6128).

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for pythoncyc?  I have not used that library before but it seems like the .full_enzyme_name() function would only return that.  Is there another function to get the ec-code?

Comment: It seems that `ec_number` is a key in the dictionary you get when you call [`PFrame()` with `getFrameData=True`](https://github.com/latendre/PythonCyc/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md#more-on-pframe-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BioGeek is correct, however I will post a full answer.

```
import pythoncyc
# To get ec-code
db = pythoncyc.select_organism('sco')
reaction = db["RXN1A0-6128"]
ec_code = reaction["ec_number"]

# To get genes
pgdb = pythoncyc.PGDB("sco")
genes = pgdb.genes_of_reaction("RXN1A0-6128")
```